# Flutter Login through API

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-navigation, flutter2.0, fluttermap

After Successful Login, I am getting User_id and User_type
I want to access the User_id and User_type.
By Using User_type,I want to log in the supervisor or Promoter

```
  Future postMethod() async {
    var api = Uri.parse("https://demo.likemyfiles.com/DS/api/auth/otp");
    Map mapeddate ={
      'phone':_phone.text,
      'otp':_otp.text,
    };
    //7404745159
    //8059482819
      final response = await http.post(api, body: mapeddate);
      print(response.body);
```

Output Will be:-

```
 {"error":false,"login":"success","user_id":"3","user_type":"1"}
```

Now I want to Access this user_type to login into the Supervisor and if the User_type:-2, I want to log in to the Promoter's Window.

Also, I want to store User_id into another variable to Show it on the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode `response.body` to get `user-type`. Then apply `if-else` logic.

```
  var res = json.decode(response.body);
   if(res['user_type'] == "1"){
      // supervisor logic
   }else{
     // promotor window logic
   }
```

Also you get can user_id by using `res['user_id']`.

Comment: his `user_type` is a `String` but you compare it to an `int`. Maybe add the conversion in your code

Comment: @JohnJoe Is there any way to connect with you

Comment: you can contact me using this gmail w.seng2@gmail.com